# Javascript ES6 Classes - Method cant access class property defined inside class constructor

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

So i was trying to structure my code inside a class so it can be more organized, but iam struggling. I have the code:

```
class App {

  constructor() {

    // Get elements from DOM
    const titleBox = document.getElementById('titleBox');
    const navBox = document.getElementById('navBox');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.header__listLink');
    const headerTitle = document.getElementById('headerTitle');
    const headerSubtitle = document.getElementById('headerSubtitle');
    const ulNav = document.getElementById('ulNav');
    const ulNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ulNavLink');

    // for each nav link, add an event listener, expanding content area
    navLinks.forEach((link) => {
      link.addEventListener('click', this.clickedLinkState);
    });

  }

  clickedLinkState(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      titleBox.classList.remove("header__title-box");
      titleBox.classList.add("header__title-box--linkClicked");

      headerTitle.classList.remove("header__title");
      headerTitle.classList.add("header__title--linkClicked");

      headerSubtitle.classList.remove("header__subtitle");
      headerSubtitle.classList.add("header__subtitle--linkClicked");

      ulNav.classList.remove("header__listInline");
      ulNav.classList.add("header__listInline--linkClicked");

      navBox.classList.remove("header__nav-box");
      navBox.classList.add("header__nav-box--linkClicked");

      ulNavLinks.forEach((navLink) => {
        navLink.classList.remove("header__listLink");
        navLink.classList.add("header__listLink--linkClicked");
      });   

  }

}

const app = new App();
```

And i got the error: "main.js:40 Uncaught ReferenceError: ulNavLinks is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.clickedLinkState (main.js:40)". the 'ulNavLinks' is a nodeList.

I was trying to define the elements using 'this.titleBox = ...', for exemple, but it got even worse, i could not access it from my clickedLinkState method. Outside the class it was working.

Why i cant access the 'ulNavLinks' inside my method? and why i cant access my propesties inside the method if i declare them 'this.titleBox', 'this.navBox'?

Comment: Variables declared in the constructor function are just simple local variables of that function. They do not implicitly become object properties; you have to make those explicitly by creating properties on `this`.

Comment: The issue is with state. try 'link.addEventListener('click', this.clickedLinkState.bind(this))'

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, as for now, instance properties can only being defined inside class methods using keyword `this` ([here is the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties)).

Also there is an [experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) of supporting public/private fields, which you may use with some build steps due to poor browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `this`:

```js
class App {

  constructor() {

    // Get elements from DOM
    this.titleBox = document.getElementById('titleBox');
    this.navBox = document.getElementById('navBox');
    this.navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.header__listLink');
    this.headerTitle = document.getElementById('headerTitle');
    this.headerSubtitle = document.getElementById('headerSubtitle');
    this.ulNav = document.getElementById('ulNav');
    this.ulNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ulNavLink');

    // for each nav link, add an event listener, expanding content area
    this.navLinks.forEach((link) => {
      link.addEventListener('click', this.clickedLinkState.bind(this));
    });

  }

  clickedLinkState(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      this.titleBox.classList.remove("header__title-box");
      this.titleBox.classList.add("header__title-box--linkClicked");

      this.headerTitle.classList.remove("header__title");
      this.headerTitle.classList.add("header__title--linkClicked");

      this.headerSubtitle.classList.remove("header__subtitle");
      this.headerSubtitle.classList.add("header__subtitle--linkClicked");

      this.ulNav.classList.remove("header__listInline");
      this.ulNav.classList.add("header__listInline--linkClicked");

      this.navBox.classList.remove("header__nav-box");
      this.navBox.classList.add("header__nav-box--linkClicked");

      this.ulNavLinks.forEach((navLink) => {
        navLink.classList.remove("header__listLink");
        navLink.classList.add("header__listLink--linkClicked");
      });   

  }

}

const app = new App();
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So i guess the problem was: my method 'clickedLinkState' was not able to access the properties declared inside the constructor, and when we used "this.clickedLinkState.bind(this)" the "bind()" made possible for my method to access those properties, right? Thanks guys. I learned something important.

Comment: Yes, `bind(this)` returns a function that calls your function but makes sure that `this` is the value you passed into `bind`